# Can somebody tell me How , i can solve it , and how i can learn it

Tags: assembly, mips

assume the following program  run in a 32-bit little-endian MIPS processor

```
addi sr1. sr0, 0x80000000
and  sr3, sr2, sr1
beq  sr3, sr0, end 
addi sr2, sr2, 1

end:
```

1. Register `sr2` stores `x`, a signed integer. What is the function executed by the program , written in a high  level language?
2. What is the value stored in `Sr2`, at end of the program , if `Sr2=0xfffffff5`

Please can somebody tell me , how where i can start learning or any book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late here so take this with a grain of salt.

The function increment x if it is negative

```
int unknown(int x) { return x<0 ? ++x : x;}
```

The first instruction set `$r1` to the value `0x80000000` that is a bit mask. This use the fact that `$0` is always `0`, so `$r1 = 0 + 0x80000000 = 0x80000000`.

The second instruction ands `$r2` (the `x` value) with `$r1` (the bit mask) and store the result in `$r3`. This result is `0x80000000` if and only if `x` is negative (see the Two Complement format) otherwise is zero.

The third instruction jump to the end if `$r3` is zero, i.e. if `x` is positive or zero.

The last instruction increment `x` and is executed only if `x` is negative.

If `$r2 = 0xfffffff5` then `x` is `-11` (again Two complement).
 So after the function `x` is `-10` and so `$r2 = 0xfffffff6`.

Note: to convert to and from Two complement just not the number and add one.

Comment: @LinoKingo A good course on MIPS is available here ([vol1](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2015sp/MIPS_Vol1.pdf) and [vol2](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2015sp/MIPS_Vol2.pdf)). A more user friendly guide is also [here](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~solmi/teaching/arch_2002-2003/AssemblyLanguageProgDoc.pdf)